# Method to solve this integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I would like to ask does anyone know how to integrate $\sqrt{x}(1-x)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ from 0 to 1. The given answer is 0.4994.  I've spent a long time to think how to solve it but still failed. Hope anyone could explain for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The integral is a so-called Beta Function.  The answer is $$\frac1{21} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \Gamma \left ( \frac14 \right )^2 \approx 0.49944$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Beta integral (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

$$\int_0^1 t^{1/2}(1-t)^{1/4}dt=\int_0^1 t^{3/2-1}(1-t)^{5/4-1}dt=B(3/2,5/4)=\dfrac{\Gamma(3/2)\Gamma(5/4)}{\Gamma(11/4)}=$$

$$=\dfrac{2}{21}\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi} \ \Gamma(1/4)}{\Gamma(3/4)}=0.4994395342...$$

(using functional equation $\Gamma(x+1)=x \Gamma(x)$ and relationship $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$.)

A further simplication could be done because, due to complements' formula $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\dfrac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}$ we have, for $x=1/4$

$\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(3/4)=\sqrt{2}\pi$, thus $\Gamma(3/4)=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{\Gamma(1/4)}.$